# Android application not found the resource ID for the activity

Tags: android, android-layout, thread-safety, android-camera, surfaceview

Very strange behavior. My application works in landscape mode only. for this i do the following

```
<activity 
        android:name=".CopyOfRecordVideoActivityCopy"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
```

**My Layout is in layout-land folder**

When i open this activity first then it open in landscape mode. when i play a video using intent in this activity in portrait mode. After completion of video it comes back to this screen i press home button of device. If i again open this activity it displays an exception for resource not found. If i put the layout.xml in layout folder then application works but in both mode. How to resolve this error of resource not found.

Answer (score 0):

instead of `android:name=".CopyOfRecordVideoActivityCopy"` use fully qualified class name.
something like `android:name="com.my.package.CopyOfRecordVideoActivityCopy"`

Comment: I used full path. but for code security i wrote this.

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct way is to have 2 layouts, one for landsacpe in `layout-land` folder and one in `layout` folder. Then, android will do its magic, the layout will be switched automatically its time the app switched its orientation.

Comment: you are right. But the surfaceview i am using in the java file will be destroyed.

Comment: @AndroidDeveloper Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: I integrate Camera and SurfaceView in the java class to record video. When video recording is complete then it shows the playbutton on surface view to play the recorded video.                                                              After seeing full video of 40 secs user will come back to same activity with play button and surface view. According to your answer that play button and surface view will be destroyed because of recreation of activity. Right?